# Are you familiar with <ins> tag in html?

Tags: html, tags

I just found that google uses this tag for adsense,

but seems it also works without this tag,why they prefer to use it?

Comment: Nope. Part of HTML 4.0 http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/alist.html

Comment: "...why they prefer to use it?" I dunno ... because they can?

Comment: It is part of HTML4 - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/elements.html

Comment: Not just in adsense, they use it everywhere. For example in a 404 page: http://google.com/404

Answer (score 14):

The `<ins>` tag is used to indicate content that is inserted into a page and indicates changes to a document.  According to the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-ins) this was intended primarily for use in marking up versioning of a document.

Clients that aware of this tag may choose to display content inside this tag differently or not at all depending on what they are designed to do.  This is very much semantic HTML

As for why Google decide to use it I couldn't say

Answer (score 4):

INS is semantic tag describing something that is inserted to the text after the text was already published. It is not a big deal, it is I guess used by their robots to understand something they care about.

Answer (score 3):

Adding semantics to markup allows tools to extract more meta data from them. Google is in the business of writing such tools, so has good reason to encourage the use of code that they can use.